# All usb ports doesnt work, the mouse laser flashes but doesnt work

Tags: usb, mouse

I received a PC with not-working usb ports. Strange thing is that when I plug my very basic USB mouse which in other PCs works just fine, the laser flashes (so the voltage is there) but it doesnt work, the cursor is not moving. The PC has windows xp and motherboard Asus M2N-E.

Was thinking that the problem may be driver-related, but I booted the pc from Linux CentOS 6.5 LiveCD and the same situation appeared. Laser was flashing, but the mouse cursor wasnt able to move. The ps/2 mouse works just fine. In BIOS USB and USB2 and USB Legacy are ENABLED.

Comment: This is probably a superuser question, but for sure there's something non functional on that motherboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do any other USB devices work in XP such as a usb drive?

Can you confirm you have tried all the USB ports?

Have you tried disabling the Legacy USB support?

Comment: All ports are dead, tried also a usb stick in windows - not recognized, disabling legacy support didnt resolve the issue aswell

Comment: oh! it works, disabling legacy support and reinstalling the USB drivers seems to resolve the problem o_o. thx!

Answer (score 1):

reads like either the USB chip itself (if there is a single one) is damaged somehow or there might be a short cicuit in one of the connectors.
Maybe you will be able to see a small crack on the chip and or the lines to your ports.

you might want to check if you can see any dirt or similiar items/small objects short circuit one of the port.

additionally you could debug the usb "hub" which provides these ports, usually called the root hub.
for linux you could install and/or mount the usbfs to have debug info, but depending on the time you want to spend for "fixing" this it might be way cheaper to just buy a pci(X) USB card.

Comment: Disabling USB LEGACY SUPPORT in BIOS and resinstalling the drivers seems to resolve the problem. But thanks for you input Dennis!

Comment: that's a first for me that deactivating actually helps, good to know for further support.